# Read output from command line using pyserial

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

```
import serial
def main():
    print("\nInitializing serial connection")
    console = serial.Serial(
        port='COM14',
        baudrate=115200,
        parity="N",
        stopbits=1,
        bytesize=8,
        timeout=5
    )
    cmd1 = "su"
    cmd2 = 'wlarm rssi'
    console.write(str.encode(cmd1 + '\n'))
    console.write(str.encode(cmd2 + '\n'))
    print(console.read(50))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code will print: b'su\r\r\nconsole:/ # wlarm rssi\r\r\n-37\r\nconsole:/ # '

The output that I would like to have would be: -37

How can I get rid of all the other nonsense that I don't need and just print '-37'?